# TypeScript error: Cannot use namespace 'Optional' as a type. TS2709 while trying to make type files for 3rd party lib

Tags: typescript

I am trying to make type files for a 3rd party lib [optional-js](https://github.com/JasonStorey/Optional.js)

it is set up like the following

index.js

```
var Optional = require('./lib/optional.js');

module.exports = {
    empty: function empty() {
        return new Optional();
    },
    of: function of(value) {
        if (value === undefined || value === null) {
            throw new Error('value is not defined');
        }
        return new Optional(value);
    },
    ofNullable: function ofNullable(value) {
        return new Optional(value);
    }
};
```

optional.js

```
...
...
module.exports = Optional;
```

I for the life of me cannot figure out what to do to create types for this thing short of re-writting the whole library in typescript ([which I did](https://gist.github.com/fieldju/fa89ab4ac53d5bcafb25ec0968995ca3), but I would rather just contribute proper type files).

I have the following

index.d.ts

```js
import Optional from './lib/optional';
export declare function ofNullable<T>(value: T | undefined | null): Optional<T>;
export declare function of<T>(value: T | null | undefined): Optional<T>;
export declare function empty(): Optional<null>;
```

optional.d.ts

```js
export default class Optional<T> {
    private readonly _value;
    constructor(value?: T | null | undefined);
    ...
    ...
}
```

When I try to use this in another lib

```js
import Optional from 'optional-js';

...

const path: Optional<string> = Optional.ofNullable(this.props.match.params.path);
```

I get the following error

```
TypeScript error: Cannot use namespace 'Optional' as a type.  TS2709
```

Comment: Do you want to allow users to create new instances from your `Optional` class?

Comment: ```Do you want to allow users to create new instances from your Optional class?```
The way the lib is set up by design is to only allow creation of the Optional through `fromNullable`, `of` and `empty` methods.

Answer (score 1):

If users haven't access to the constructor of `Optional`, then do not declare it as a `class` (the class is your implementation details). In `optional.d.ts`:

```
export interface Optional<T> {
    /* … only public members here … */
}
```

In `index.d.ts`, you can import and reexport `Optional`:

```
import { Optional } from './lib/optional';
export { Optional };
// …
```

Or, you can directly write and export the type `Optional` in `index.d.ts`.

Then, from another lib:

```
import { ofNullable, Optional } from 'optional-js';
// …
const path: Optional<string> = ofNullable(this.props.match.params.path);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by merging to two files into a single class definition.

```js
export default class Optional<T> {
  private readonly _value;
  private constructor(value?: T | null | undefined);

  /**
   * Returns an Optional describing the given value, if non-null, otherwise returns an empty Optional.
   *
   * @typeparam T the type of the value
   * @param value the possibly-null value to describe
   * @return an Optional with a present value if the specified value is non-null, otherwise an empty Optional
   */
  static ofNullable<T>(value: T | undefined | null): Optional<T>;

  /**
   * Returns an Optional describing the given non-null value.
   *
   * @typeparam T the type of the value
   * @param value the value to describe, which must be non-null
   * @return an Optional with the value present
   * @throws Error if value is null
   */
  static of<T>(value: T | null | undefined): Optional<T>;

  /**
   * Returns an empty Optional instance. No value is present for this Optional.
   *
   * @return an empty Optional
   */
  static empty(): Optional<null>;

  /**
   * If a value is present in this Optional, returns the value, otherwise throws an Error.
   *
   * @return the non-null value held by this Optional
   * @throws Error if the value is null;
   */
  get(): T | null | undefined;

  /**
   * Return true if there is a value present, otherwise false.
   *
   * @return true if there is a value present, otherwise false
   */
  isPresent(): boolean;

  /**
   * If a value is present, invoke the specified consumer with the value, otherwise do nothing.
   *
   * @param consumer function to be executed if a value is present
   */
  ifPresent(consumer: (value: T) => void): void;

  /**
   * If a value is present, and the value matches the given predicate, return an Optional describing the value,
   * otherwise return an empty Optional.
   *
   * @param predicate A predicate to apply to the value, if present
   * @return an Optional describing the value of this Optional if a value is present and the value matches the given
   * predicate, otherwise an empty Optional
   * @throws Error if the predicate is null
   */
  filter(predicate: (value: T) => boolean): Optional<T | null | undefined>;

  /**
   * If a value is present, apply the provided mapping function to it, and if the result is non-null,
   * return an Optional describing the result. Otherwise return an empty Optional.
   *
   * @typeparam U The type of the result of the mapping function
   * @param mapper a mapping function to apply to the value, if present.
   * @return an Optional describing the result of applying a mapping function to the value of this Optional,
   * if a value is present, otherwise an empty Optional
   * @throws Error if the mapping function is null
   */
  map<U>(mapper: (value: T) => U | undefined | null): Optional<U>;

  /**
   * If a value is present, apply the provided Optional-bearing mapping function to it, return that result,
   * otherwise return an empty Optional. This method is similar to map(Function), but the provided mapper is one whose
   * result is already an Optional, and if invoked, flatMap does not wrap it with an additional Optional.
   *
   * @typeparam U The type parameter to the Optional returned by the mapping function
   * @param mapper a mapping function to apply to the value, if present the mapping function
   * @return the result of applying an Optional-bearing mapping function to the value of this Optional,
   * if a value is present, otherwise an empty Optional
   * @throws Error if the mapping function is null or returns a null result
   */
  flatMap<U>(mapper: (value: T) => Optional<U> | undefined | null): Optional<U>;

  /**
   * If a value is present, returns the value, otherwise returns other.
   *
   * @param other the value to be returned, if no value is present. May be null.
   * @return the value, if present, otherwise other
   */
  orElse(other: T): T;

  /**
   * If a value is present, returns the value, otherwise returns the result produced by the supplying function.
   *
   * @param supplier the supplying function that produces a value to be returned
   * @return the value, if present, otherwise the result produced by the supplying function
   * @throws Error if no value is present and the supplying function is null
   */
  orElseGet(supplier: () => T): T;

  /**
   * If a value is present, returns the value, otherwise throws an exception produced by the exception supplying function.
   *
   * @param exceptionSupplier the supplying function that produces an exception to be thrown
   * @return the value, if present
   * @throws Error if no value is present and the exception supplying function is null
   */
  orElseThrow(exceptionSupplier: () => Error): T;

  /**
   * If a value is present, performs the given action with the value, otherwise performs the given empty-based action.
   *
   * @param action the action to be performed, if a value is present
   * @param emptyAction the empty-based action to be performed, if no value is present
   * @throws if a value is present and the given action is null, or no value is present and the given empty-based action is null.
   */
  ifPresentOrElse(action: (value: T) => void, emptyAction: () => void): void;

  /**
   * If a value is present, returns an Optional describing the value, otherwise returns an Optional produced by the supplying function.
   *
   * @param optionalSupplier the supplying function that produces an Optional to be returned
   * @return returns an Optional describing the value of this Optional, if a value is present,
   * otherwise an Optional produced by the supplying function.
   * @throws Error if the supplying function is null or produces a null result
   */
  or(optionalSupplier: () => Optional<T>): Optional<T>;
}
```

I marked the constructor as private since you can't construct the class since it, isn't actually exported. Is this a hack?

Comment: But then you can't import just the exported member you need: `import { ofNullable } from 'optional-js'` won't compile. Other remark: `export default` is not correct in your case. In your JS you don't export all your members as `default`. So, you should declare the class, then write: `export = Optional`. But your TS definitions still don't describe the implementation.